# Is it a good practice to perform direct database access in the code-behind of an ASP.NET page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am an experienced developer but I am new to web application development.  Now I am in charge of developing a new web application and I could really use some input from experienced web developers out there.

I'd like to understand exactly what experienced web developers do in the code-behind pages.  At first I thought it was best to have a rule that all the database access and business logic should be performed in classes external to the code-behind pages.  My thought was that only logic necessary for the web form would be performed in the code-behind.  I still think that all the business logic should be performed in other classes but I'm beginning to think it would be alright if the code-behind had access to the database to query it directly rather than having to call other classes to receive a dataset or collection back.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to be more specific?  The title is incredibly vague and makes it likely to be closed.  However, it sounds like your question might simply be "Is it a good practice to perform direct database access in the code-behind of an ASP.NET page, or should all database access be done behind an abstraction?"  That might pick up some better answers than a question asking for a generic list of "best" practices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go strictly with asp.net (and don't use MVC models), then you are on the right track considering N-tier development and separation.

Your code-behind should be related to presentation/UI, and should rely on middle tier layers for business logic etc.

In general the easiest way to split up the app, is to have multiple projects in a VS solution, such as:

- ASP.NET Web application project (Presentation/UI)
- C# class library - Business Logic Layer
- C# class library - Data Layer
- Database (SQL or otherwise)

You can of course have many other libraries and layers as needed, but essentially the n-tier approach that works in non-web environments applies well using the same principles here.

Comment: Thank you KP.  That is exactly how I have my solution setup.  Is it alright to allow the ASP.Net project to access the database without going through the Business Layer if we are just performing queries?  It seems like we are going through a lot of trouble trying to avoid that and life would be much simpler if if we can just query to the database directly from the code-behind.

Comment: I always prefer a layer in between code-behind and DB, but even some asp.net web controls (SQLDataSource for example), allow SQL queries directly in markup for simplicity. There is definitely no perfect answer to this...